# Calculated Column Next Year in Text Format - (Sharepoint 2013 on Prem)

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, sharepoint-server

I have a calculated field [Current Year] in Text Format:

```
=TEXT(Created,"YYYY")
```

which displays "2019" in Text Format.

But I also want to create a new Column with a calculated column that is next year (also in Text format as above)

I tried (logically I thought)

```
=TEXT(Created,"YYYY"+1)
```

But it gave 2,020!! NOT "2020".

Please can someone suggest the Calculation for Next Year in Text Format.
So it appears as (in this case) 2020.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below formula.

```
=(YEAR(Created)+1)&""
```

For details please refer to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)) article from Microsoft

Comment: Superb! works perfectly - Thank You